# Is there a way to map the .rodata segment in a different program header?

Tags: linux, linker, ld

In `readelf --segments` output for a shared library (linux x86_64), the first few program headers are:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000984 0x0000000000000984  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000dc8 0x0000000000200dc8 0x0000000000200dc8
                 0x0000000000000280 0x0000000000000288  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000de8 0x0000000000200de8 0x0000000000200de8
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     8
```

These map the following respective sections:

```
Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
   01     .init_array .fini_array .jcr .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss
   02     .dynamic
```

I'm using the gnu linker (binutils ld.bfd), and would like to know the black magic incantations to do either of the following:

1. Create an additional (R-mode) LOAD Program Header to hold the
   `.rodata` section, so that I can have the `.data`, `.bss` and `.rodata` all
   near each other (whereas the default link layout puts my `.rodata`
   ~0x200000 bytes away from my `.data`)
2. Colocate the `.rodata` section contents with `.data` and `.bss` in the RW
   (second) load segment.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to do 2.  First dump the default linker script, passing `-Wl,-verbose` to the compiler driver link step, and then modifying that by removing the lines:

```
.rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
.rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
```

And adding them back in with the `.data` sections:

```
.data           :
{
  *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
  *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
  *(.rodata1)
  SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
}
```

The modified linker script can be used with `-Wl,-T,pathToThatScript`